# Colon and semi-colon sentence structure

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

I have not seen a semi-colon used in Spanish writing and I'm wondering whether it can be directly used under the rules of English grammar. Consider the following sentence for example.

> The vaccine is tetravalent and comprises: proteins x, y, z; protein chains a, b, c; aluminium oxide; and a preserving agents.

Is this translation valid?

> La vacuna es tetravalente y comprende: proteínas x, y, z;
> cadenas de proteínas a, b y c; óxido de aluminio; y agentes conservantes.

Comment: English is not your native language, right? So, first, you have to fix the English: x, y, z proteins, a, b, c protein chains, aluminium oxide and preserving agents.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie yes thats the correct order, i.e. ... comprising :x, y, and z proteins; a, b, and c protein chains; .... However, the colon/semi-colon structure broken-up by commas is formal (scientific) English.

Comment: In English, if you have a colon or don't have a colon, a list like this can be separated **by commas** and does not require a semi-colon at all.

Comment: https://www.rae.es/duda-linguistica/cuando-se-usa-el-punto-y-coma Check the RAE before posting and please show that or other research. Translation and punctuation are not the same thing. Also, you need to fix your English before asking. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for the link, upvoted. English ....  I'm a senior Academic Editor for a major international scientific journal (previously multiple journals): I think the shoe is on the other foot. Again thanks for the link.

Comment: And I too am an English editor. There is no need for all those semi-colons after the colon. The list separated by commas and an and is enough. X is Y and comprises: A, B, C, and D. Much clearer. Of course, if you keep the protein letters and protein chains at the end, it's harder to read.

Comment: @Lambie do you write scientific English, papers or grants?

Comment: No, I edit papers. I don't write them.

Comment: @Lambie The semi-colon is never *required* in English grammar; that doesn't change how it **can** be used. You omitted a comma when you said "aluminium oxide and preserving agents", but that comma is not required either (although it is often considered more clear in meaning to use the so-called Oxford comma). It's not helpful to say "you could have put a comma there" if you had asked about correctly not using a comma there.

Comment: @el_menjurje I didn't say a semi-colon was required. I'm saying there is no need for all those semi-colons after the colon. So, *maybe your comment should be directed to the OP and not me since I said I would not use them here*. The use of the Oxford comma is up to the writer/editor.

Comment: @Lambie The comma before the 'and' as described by el_menjurje is correct. This is not needed. In grant writing `:` followed by `;` are used a lot.

Comment: @M__  First, I never said the semi-colon was required in English (as claimed by el_menjurje. And second, an Oxford comma can always be used in a list of three or more items. You can do as you please. I don't care.

Comment: @Lambie If someone asks how to use something, commenting "do it some other way" is neither useful nor serves any purpose unless the question was "do I have to use this thing or should I do it some other way". You **can** use it, so *how* you use it would be a useful contribution toward the specific question that was asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sobre el uso del punto y coma**

> ...and I'm wondering whether it can be directly used under the rules of English grammar.

A grandes rasgos, sí. Para comenzar, básicamente lo qué tiene para decir [La Academia](https://www.rae.es/dpd/punto%20y%20coma) sobre los usos posibles:

- Separar cláusulas independientes pero estrechamente relacionadas y que a juicio de quien escribe estén tan relacionadas de modo que no sea necesario usar un punto. Este uso probablemente sea el más subjetivo.
- Separar enumeraciones con coma. Tu ejemplo está OK escribiendo ‘y’ en enumeraciones con coma, salvo para evitar cacofonías.
- En oraciones largas, para introducir conjunciones adversativas. Suele verse sobre todo con ‘no obstante’ y ‘sin embargo’, ya que éstos conectores suelen preceder a una coma.
- Para separar elementos de una lista que ‘presenten una cierta complejidad’—lo cual da aun más lugar a la subjetividad para definir lo que es ‘complejo’. Este uso es muy raro ya que en general las *bullet lists* suelen hacerse justamente para evitar frases demasiado largas y la difícil lectura que eso conllevaría.

PARÉNTESIS

Explico el último punto. Compárese frases como:

> ¿Cuál es el país más grande del mundo: Estados Unidos, Rusia, China, Japón o Canadá?

> ¿Cuál es el país más grande del mundo?
>
> - Estados Unidos
> - Rusia
> - China
> - Japón
> - Canadá

El segundo estilo es más legible, y ni hablar si hay más elementos. Pero agregar más símbolos de puntuación allí entorpecería la lectura: cada elemento ya está perfectamente demarcado por la viñeta y los saltos de línea. Por lo tanto, me parece un yerro por parte de la ‘casta’ el legislar acerca del uso del punto y coma en listas. Sólo tendría sentido si todos los ítems forman parte de una única oración y cada uno presenta cierta longitud, lo cual me haría pensar si realmente vale la pena ponerlos como una lista o si en realidad se trata de varias oraciones/párrafos.

Yo soy hincha de lo que el sr. [Stylemanual](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/punctuation-and-capitalisation/semicolons) tiene para decir, incluso sabiendo que son reglas que supuestamente sólo valen para el inglés:

> You don’t need a semicolon at the end of each list item for bullet and numbered lists. It clutters the list and makes it hard to read.

FIN PARÉNTESIS

Retomo la pregunta. Encontré dos principales diferencias fundamentales aunque son muy sutiles y difícil de calificar como ‘diferencias’:

- En inglés, para iniciar una cláusula interrogativa luego de otra no interrogativa, suele y/o puede usarse el punto y coma. En español es más raro verlo porque existe el ¿ signo de apertura; además de que este último es obligatorio incluso aunque se decida separar con punto y coma—a menos que seas del Team Neruda.

> La noche es fría; el bosque está desnudo; ¿es el viento el que gime en la soledad? (Andahazi Piadosas [Arg. 1999])

> The night is cold; the forest is naked; is it the wind that is moaning in the loneliness?

- No se debe usar el punto y coma en reemplazo de la coma, los dos puntos (‘introducen’ una idea nueva con pausa mayor a ;), ni con conectores que no los requieren. Hasta ahí ambos idiomas concuerdan, pero por lo que veo parecería ser que en inglés [*but* no suele admite el símbolo en cuestión](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/semi), mientras que con *pero* la regla es un poco más laxa (cf. el primer enlace).

**Sobre la falta de uso en castellano**

> I have not seen a semi-colon used in Spanish...

Y explicar esto lo veo aun más difícil. El invento del punto y coma como separador viene de Italia; cuando lo introdujeron en España los escritores [sintieron que no era necesario](https://www.rae.es/ortograf%c3%ada/el-punto-y-coma#3.4.3) (: lo podía reemplazar) mientras que en Inglaterra sí les fue útil. Algo similar pasó con la — raya, yo creo que son cosas que pegan o no pegan de acuerdo a las costrumbres y los ritmos que maneja la pronunciación de cada idioma.